# Duplicates ActivityId in TPL ETW Semantic Logging

Tags: task-parallel-library, azure-service-fabric, etw

I am running a Service Fabric application and the the events are being logged into Elasticsearch. I am using out of process semantic logging , elastic search sink.

And for correlating the events, i use Activity Id and Relative Activity Id.

The problem is that some logs that are begin logged from different partitions have same activity Id and I am having difficulties correlating those events.

Is activity id is generated as full GUIDs, Most of the activities have zeros in the middle part of the GUID.

Is it possible to generate full GUIDs for activity Id without explicitly specifying the Current activity id for the Thread.